# R ggplot2 introduce slight smoothing to a line graph with only a few datapoints

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure if this is a programming question or not...

If I have the data below, which produces a 'spiky' chart, and I'd like to produce a slightly smoothed one using ggplot2 how do I go about it most elegantly. The usual smoothing methods remove too much information. One way I'm considering is to interpolate an extra two data points in between the current set and then take a 2 period moving average or something. That seems like a lot of hard work to code manually so I'll take an answer that automates that elegantly as a last resort.

```
a=data.frame(year=paste('FY',2001:2012,sep='.'),values=rnorm(12))
library(ggplot2)
```

As you can see this is spiky and visually unappealing

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+geom_line()
```

And this removes too much information from the graph

```
ggplot(a,aes(x=year,y=values,group=1))+stat_smooth(se=F)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try a polynomial. Since the x-axis variable has 12 unique values, you can use polynomials up to the 11th degree. Furthermore, you should use a continuos scale for the x-axis to achieve a smooth curve.

Here's an example of an 8th-order polynomial:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = year, y = values, group = 1))+
  stat_smooth(aes(x = seq(length(unique(year)))), # continuous x-axis
              se = F, method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 8)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(length(unique(a$year))), 
                     labels = levels(a$year)) # original labels
```

Here, `method = "lm"` means, that a linear model is used. The second argument of the `poly` function specifies the degree.
[image]

Comment: thanks @SvenHohenstein that works for the single graph. I'm struggling to make it align horizontally for multiple data sets and to extend the x-axis so I need to go back to the drawing board a little though..

Comment: @SvenHohenstein A very nice approach. In my case I want to do the same but my polynomial can't give negative values. Is it possible to put a lower limit on stat_smooth? Thanks

Comment: @pacomet You cannot specify a limit in `stat_smooth`. You should search for a certain smoothing function for your data that can be used in `stat_smooth`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Would you also recommend to switch from `scale_x_date` to `scale_x_continuous` to make a line smoother in case of monthly values?

Comment: @Talik3233 It depends on your preferences. There's nothing wrong with a classic continuous scale when the data are appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid losing **too much information** from the data, below could be a better approach, that works good for large datasets:

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape)
a$smooth<-rollmean(a$values,3,fill="extend") # 2nd parameter defines smoothness 
ggplot(melt(a),aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable,group=variable))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Here is a better example:

```
a <- data.frame(year=1:10,values=sin(1:10)+runif(10))
a$smooth<-rollmean(a$values,3,fill="extend")
ggplot(melt(a,id.vars="year"),aes(x=year,y=value,color=variable,
      group=variable))+geom_line(size=2)
```

[image]