# R:ggplot2 get both columns on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have csv file with many columns first column of the csv is user_id. Other columns are realted to different actions that user has taken. I want to plot two columns from this csv file on one ggplot with lines.

```
userid    Action1TakenTimes Action2TakenTimes
1                    0             4
2                    6             4
3                    0             1
4                    8            23
5                    4             3
6                    1             1
```

I have converted the csv file to R data table and did the simple plot but I want do a ggplot with a smooth lines connecting the points.

```
plot(log(mytable.data$Action1TakenTimes))
plot(log(mytable.data$Action2TakenTimes))
```

I went over following tutorial but couldn't find a similar example: 
http://www.ceb-institute.org/bbs/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/handout_ggplot2.pdf

Comment: I wonder if you even tried to Google this. When I do, I get 5-10 SO posts answering exactly that

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg <- melt(mytable.data,id="userid")
ggplot(gg,aes(x=userid,y=log(value),color=variable))+geom_line()
```

`ggplot` expects the data in so-called "long" format, with all the values in one column, and a second column which distinguishes the different groups. Your data is in "wide" format, with the different groups in different columns. To convert, use `melt(...)` in the `reshape2` package.

This is a very common pattern with `ggplot`.

One problem with your data is that you're taking log(0), which produces `-Inf`. Smoothing is meaningless in that situation. If there were no infinities you could add `+stat_smooth()` to the end of the `ggplot(...)` line to generate a loess smoothed curve.

Comment: I was just about to press "Post your answer"... The funniest thing is that we both were too lazy to look for a duplicate (which probably exist in great counts)

Comment: Is there a way to make the lines smoother?

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, have you heard of a great tool called "Google"? Try putting a search query of "plot smooth lines in ggplot" and see magic, only magic. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789502/r-ggplot2-introduce-slight-smoothing-to-a-line-graph-with-only-a-few-datapoints) one example

Comment: @DavidArenburg Actually, `stat_smooth(...)` (from the answers to duplicates), doesn't work here, because log(0) produces `NAs` and evidently `loess(...)` doesn't like `NAs`.

Comment: What about `rollmean`? Either way the OP didn't try to look it up first

Comment: Actually `log(0)` produces `-Inf` rather than `NA`s. `NA`s are not a problem as you can parse `na.rm = T` to `stat_smooth`. The OP also can use other methods rather than just `loess` by using the `method` argument